# Solving a second order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem solving the following second order partial differential equation:

$\frac{\partial ^2p}{\partial x^2}=0$

Does anyone know how it can be solved?

Comment: In fact, there is nothing partial about it.

Comment: Okay, but do you know how it can be solved?

Comment: Yes: the same way as an _ordinary_ differential equation would.

Comment: $p$ is a function of what variables ?

Comment: P is a function of different variables, like permeability and viscosity. But these variables are assumed constant in this exercise.

Comment: Just integrate twice w.r.t. $x$, but keep in mind that the constant of integration that you would get in an ODE is now a constant function w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.